# How to correct the Xcode bug of creating lproj folders in the en.lproj folder?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, localization

I had a Localizable.strings file in my project for which I wanted to add more localizations.

So I went to the Project Settings and clicked the "+" to add languages. Somehow I cannot do that anymore on the right panel as there is no "+" button.

Xcode creates the cn.lproj folder inside the en.lproj folder in the file system which is messy but some other lproj folders such as de.lproj do get created where they belong.

How can I move an xx.lproj folder to where it belongs without breaking everything in Xcode? I am afraid leaving them where xcode is putting them can cause errors at run time because cn.lproj should not be a sub-folder of en.lproj.

Answer (score 3):

As it turns out it's an Xcode bug, but fortunately it can be resolved.

First step is to backup your project. Then move the wrongfully placed lproj folders out of en.lproj and if you want, put all of them in a localized subfolder.
Then delete all the link-broken files (red) from the Project Navigator. For the stacked files that have an arrow you will have to delete the root item. Do not choose "Move to Trash". Then make sure in the Project Settings you have all the localizations you want. Drag the "localized" sobfolder containing all the lproj folders into Xcode wherever you want it to be, and make sure it gets added to the current target (Add to target checkmark must be checked in the list). In my case everything was functional as expected after doing this. And as a nice side effect I got rid of these annoying stacked files with the arrow and instead have a very clear group structure consisting of a localized and several lproj folders which makes much more sense to me.

Comment: This is the best answer. Xcode started screwing up my project after adding the forth language. I went back to the last 'good' commit in git, added the next language, but with a minimum of files (2 Storyboards). Then I copied the content of the english folder to the new lproj folder and dragged that folder into Xcode as you described. Thats not pretty, but it works. I still have some assets left in the stacked mode (with the i18n arrow), but I'm going to leave them where they are....   I've tried for hours to find a better solution, but Xcode definitely fails and I can't find the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to add a localization would be through your Project Info pane in Xcode.

It looks like this:

[image: Here's the most obvious way to add a localization via Xcode]

I would think trying to do it any other way might be asking for trouble (or hassle).

Comment: That's what I did and Xcode is creating randomly lproj folders inside the en.lproj folder which is definitely not correct. See question.

Comment: When I add localizations into that test project you see up there, it's adding "`zh-Hans.lproj`" and "`de.lproj`" folders in the correct places. You might want to try creating a tiny test project like I did and see how the structure is, and then check the paths to your storyboard or strings file and make certain that the localized files (and actually, the file paths) from your current project look like the ones in the quickly created test project.

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: this is correct theoretically, and good advice as well. In practice, Xcode (5.1.1) will spread new .*lproj folders inside existing .lproj folders. I havn't found a pattern when this happens, but it does. In addition to that, a lots of the copy bundle identifiers are red, even with a new testproject. I guess Xcode is really, really broken here.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should have a folder en.lpoj for English.
Now if you click "+" and choose xx as language you should get another one named "xx.lpoj" nearby of the old one (on the same level so to say) and NOT inside the en.lproj.
So delete this wrong sub-folder and do it again ...

Comment: Did it again many times but certain languages just keep getting created inside en.lproj.